# Visual Studio 2015 - Can't get started

Tags: visual-studio

There are two main issues that prevent me from starting using Visual Studio properly:

1. When I create new project and it asks for target platform, there is no Windows 7 option. Only options are for Windows 10, which I don't have.
2. When I try to run a program it asks me to connect a Windows phone, which I don't have and I don't really understand why it is required if I'm making a program for the desktop version of Windows.

Comment: Which project template are you selecting? It sounds like you're selecting either the Universal App or Windows Phone template rather than the desktop one. I don't have 2015 installed on this machine to check exactly which template you should be selecting.

Comment: There are two editions of the free version of Visual Studio.  You picked the wrong one.  Use the "for Desktop" edition instead.  You need to mention those details btw, nobody can guess at this.  Not me either.